# Powering LED Lamp from Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm about to embark on my first (actually useful) Arduino project. I have a Kinect setup to detect when I get close to my PC, and I can send a message to my Arduino board to switch on a LED when I get close, and turn it off when I get far away.

Now, I want to make a full lamp, rather than just 1 LED, however, I have a limited knowledge of electronics.

What will I need to read up on before I start buying parts and building this lamp to make sure I don't blow the board/mess anything else up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number one, there is no way that Arduino will be able to supply power for an 120v AC light bulb. If you know that you are better off than some already!

I frequently point new Arduino users toward Arduino Playground, it has quite a bit of useful and important information about the basics.

If you want to make a 'lamp', you should investigate the links about [connecting hardware to Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc//Main/InterfacingWithHardware#PwrSup). AND…definitely learn & understand the limits, capabilities, and **limits** of your Arduino. The following is very important and applies to almost every Arduino alive. Not knowing this may drastically shorten the life expectancy of your Arduino -

> **Absolute Maximum Ratings**
>
> DC Current per I/O Pin ........... **40.0 mA**
>
> DC Current VCC and GND Pins...... **200.0 mA**
>
> 1 VCC pin: Means these Arduinos can Source a **total of 200mA**
>
> 2 GND pins: Means these Arduinos can Sink a **total of 400mA**

There are not only maximum current limits per pin and per board, there are also limits on total current per port (group of pins) too!
[This Page](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations) has all the info you should need about that.

You will need to discover how much power (volts & milliAmps) your 'lamp' will require. Then, you can determine how to power & switch it properly. Anything I would consider a 'lamp' would likely need to be powered separately from Arduino and not through any of its pins or headers (common GND though!) and only switched on & off using Arduino pins.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll check out those links. Would (theoretically) it be possible to power the LED's externally and just have the Arduino send an on/off command?

Comment: Absolutely. That's usually done with a 'logic level MOSFET' used as a switch and activated by signal from Arduino pin. A nice example of how to do that here [link](http://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips?view=all)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great solution, if you are wanting to turn on an AC powered lamp from an Arduino.  If you are just wanting to control an LED, you can do that directly with a current limiting resistor to the LED from a Digital pin configured as output.

[AC Power Relay](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/119)